# Custom search page and url in multilanguage

Tags: search, multi-language

I just made a custom search page for my website in Wordpress. But I have an issue:

```
Case 1: mydomain.com/?s=test....Work
Case 2: mydomain.com/search/test....Work
Case 3: mydomain.com/en/?s=test....Work
Case 4: mydomain.com/en/search/test....Doesn't work and return 404 page.
```

I created a search page using my custom template. I changed the url to both languages to `/search` and `/en/search` respectively. But I cannot make the last case to work.

Here is the form in case you need it.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" class="search-form" method="get">

    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="<?php _e('Search request here', 'wproto'); ?>" value="<?php echo get_query_var('s'); ?>" />
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

</form>
```

Comment: Are you using a translation plugin?

Comment: @bklynM I found it from another dev. The website contains two wordpress installations that share the same theme folder.It is weird that only the last option doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself. I had to flush the permalinks on the English admin page. Now all of the above urls work.